# How to arrange my data so that ggplot xaxis datetimes are normalised into times only?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, lubridate

All my timestamps are in POSIXct at present, and ggplot keeps wanting to position one series after the other due to the date portion thats included within each datapoint.

I want to be able to still group my series separately, but plot them such that for each series, the datapoints at 10:00:02 am are positioned in the same place on the x-axis.

If I strip the the datetimes into just times using eg. strptime , they become character strings, therefore loose the numeric/continuous scale benefits.

I also considered prebuilding  in advance all possible timestamps in the range I am analyzing as character strings, but that seems like a rather blunt hammer for this problem ... (or maybe this is the right way forward?)

any ideas/suggestions welcome

Edit1:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv("date,                  timect,        values
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:00.000,        295644
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:01.000,        295781
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:02.000,        295864
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:03.000,        295897
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:04.000,        295897
04-JAN-2021, 2021-01-04 10:00:05.000,        295917
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:00.000,        299660
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:01.000,        299889
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:02.000,        300098
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:03.000,        300200
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:04.000,        300307
05-JAN-2021, 2021-01-05 10:00:05.000,        300475") 


data %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=timect,y=values,color=date))+
  geom_line()
```

What libraries functions/methods exist that allow both of the following:

1. the x-axis to still be continuous/numeric type scale
2. formatting the x-axis labels into HH:MM:SS, or at least HH:MM ?

Edit2
not sure why, but the when I tried to use the hms function before it was giving unexpected results, and I put it aside thinking it wasnt meant for this task.  On a fresh look today, it appears to be doing what I need now.

Extending on earlier example:

```
library(hms)

data %>%
mutate(hms = as_hms(timect)) %>%
group_by(date) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=hms,y=values,color=date))+
geom_line()
```

I would still be interested any feedback or suggestions.

Comment: @RonakShah , i've added one.  My question is how to get ggplot to display the datapoints for both Jan4th, and Jan5th at the same position on the x-axis , without having to resort to manually crafted xaxis (assuming this is possible)..  There seem to be many examples for doing this with dates - but i havent found anything for doing this at more granular hours:minutes amounts..

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make the date same across the dataframe and use `scale_x_datetime` to format the X-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(timect = ymd_hms(paste(Sys.Date(), format(timect, '%T')))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=timect,y=values,color=date)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels  = '%T')
```

[image]